# Stack with getMin method

Tags: java, algorithm, linked-list, stack

This should implement a stack that has a \$O(1)\$ `getMin` method. I used an auxiliary stack. Please provide comments on my solution.

```
import org.junit.Test;

public class Solution {

  @Test
  public void testEmptyStack(){
    StackMin<Integer> s = new StackMin<Integer>();
    System.out.println("----------------------");
    System.out.println("Empty stack");
    System.out.println(s.getMin());
  }

  @Test
  public void testRandomStack(){
    System.out.println("----------------------");
    StackMin<Integer> s = new StackMin<Integer>();
    s.push(2);
    s.push(-1);
    s.push(0);
    s.push(7);
    s.push(22);
    System.out.println("Random stack");
    s.printStack();
    System.out.println("Min element");
    System.out.println(s.getMin());
  }

  @Test
  public void testEqualities(){
    System.out.println("----------------------");
    StackMin<Integer> s = new StackMin<Integer>();
    s.push(2);
    s.push(-1);
    s.push(0);
    s.push(0);
    s.push(0);
    s.push(7);
    s.push(22);
    s.push(-1);
    s.push(-1);
    s.push(33);
    System.out.println("Stack with equalities");
    s.printStack();
    System.out.println("Min element");
    System.out.println(s.getMin());
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Solution e = new Solution();
    e.testEmptyStack();
    e.testRandomStack();
    e.testEqualities();
  }
}

class NodeV2<T> {
  private final T data;

  private final NodeV2<T> next;

  public NodeV2(T d, NodeV2<T> n) {
    data = d;
    next = n;
  }

  public NodeV2(T d) {
    this(d, null);
  }

  public T getData() {
    return data;
  }

  public NodeV2<T> getNext() {
    return next;
  }

}

class StackMin<T extends Comparable<T>> extends StackV2<T> {
  StackV2<T> auxiliaryStack = new StackV2<T>();

  void push(T element) {
    if (auxiliaryStack.isEmpty() || element.compareTo(auxiliaryStack.top.getData()) <= 0) {
      auxiliaryStack.push(element);
    }

    super.push(element);
  }

  T pop() {
    if (this.peek().compareTo(auxiliaryStack.peek()) <= 0) {
      auxiliaryStack.pop();
    }

    return super.pop();
  }

  public T getMin() {
    return auxiliaryStack.peek();
  }

}

class StackV2<T extends Comparable<T>> {
  NodeV2<T> top;

  void push(T element) {
    NodeV2<T> t = new NodeV2<T>(element, top);
    top = t;
  }

  T pop() {
    if (top != null) {
      T item = top.getData();
      top = top.getNext();
      return item;
    }
    return null;
  }

  T peek() {
    return top == null ? null : top.getData();
  }

  boolean isEmpty() {
    return top == null ? true : false;
  }

  public void printStack() {
    NodeV2<T> current = top;
    while (current != null) {
      System.out.println(current.getData());
      current = current.getNext();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yay, you use tests!

Darn it, you don't use tests.

Confusing? Allow me to explain. While I totally approve of you using tests, there is a lot more to it than simply putting the `@Test` annotation above them.

A test is comprised of 3 aspects: Arrange, Act and Assert. Typically a test (whether it's unit, integration, functional, end-to-end, etc) will have these aspects in explicit or implicit form. Personally I like to explicitly separate them with comments (`// Arrange`).

Why do I mention this? Note the last aspect of AAA: Assert. This tells us that, as the last step in our test, we will verify the result we have and *assert* that it is what we expected.

Doing this allows us to run the tests and **automatically** compare the result of each test with the expected outcome. In your situation you have to manually verify that each test works as expected; can you see yourself doing that when you have 300 tests instead of 3?

This brings us to another point: all modern IDE's have integrated test runners. If you have tests, you can just run these using that instead of having to use a `main()` method as entrypoint for your tests.

By adapting these changes you also won't need those println's anymore which takes away focus from your actual content.

- [Junit documentation](http://junit.org/apidocs/org/junit/Assert.html)
- [Junit tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JUnit/article.html)

Answer (score 6):

> ```
>   @Test
>   public void testRandomStack(){
>     System.out.println("----------------------");
>     StackMin<Integer> s = new StackMin<Integer>();
>     s.push(2);
>     s.push(-1);
>     s.push(0);
>     s.push(7);
>     s.push(22);
>     System.out.println("Random stack");
>     s.printStack();
>     System.out.println("Min element");
>     System.out.println(s.getMin());
>   }
> ```

What's random about this stack? I'm reminded of this.

[image: return 4; //random dice roll guaranteed to be fair]

Perhaps a better name for this would be "PsuedoRandomStack".

---

Also, may I ask what the `V2` in `NodeV2` and `StackV2` represent? It's not clear to me. As far as I can tell, these should simply be `Node` and `Stack`.

---

If I'm reading this correctly, there's no reason for a ternary condition here.

> ```
>   boolean isEmpty() {
>     return top == null ? true : false;
>   }
> ```

Why not just return the result of the expression?

```
boolean isEmpty() {
    return top == null; 
}
```

If you don't like that, perhaps add the parenthesis to make it a bit more clear and explicit what is being returned.

```
boolean isEmpty() {
    return (top == null); 
}
```

Comment: To help the OP out, what one can possibly do to fix this is to randomize the expected minimum value, then randomize a bunch of values which are greater than that...

Comment: Maybe overkill, but certainly a good idea @h.j.k.

Answer (score 2):

`NodeV2` should really be inner `static` class within `StackV2`, since it it not expected to be used standalone.

Also, assuming you do not want to modify your existing APIs for `StackV2`, consider writing helper methods for unit testing to facilitate the repetitive pushing of values into your `StackMin` instances:

```
private static <T> StackV2<T> push(final StackV2<T> stack, T... values) {
    for (final T value : values) {
        stack.push(value);
    }
    return stack;
}
```

Here, I also `return stack` so that callers of this method can daisy-chain it for other purposes if required.

Comment: Should the second argument be T[] instead? (I have never seen the notation T...)?

Comment: [Varargs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html) ;) (since 1.5)