# Union of intervals

Tags: java, sorting, collections, interval

I am trying to solve for the problem with a bunch of intervals:

```
(1,2),(2,5),(4,7),(9,11)
```

I find their union, which in the above given case would be:

```
(1,7),(9,11)
```

It will be great to get some feedback on whether I am on the right track and how I can improve upon what I have.

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class IntervalUnion{
    class Interval implements Comparable<Interval>{
        private final int left;
        private final int right;
        Interval(int left,int right){
            this.left = left;
            this.right = right;
        }
        public int getRight(){
          return this.right;
        }
        public int getLeft(){
          return this.left; 
        }
        @Override
        public int compareTo(Interval interval){
            if(this.left > interval.left){
              return 1; 
            }else if(this.left < interval.left){
              return -1;    
            }else{
              return 0;
            }
        }
        @Override
        public String toString(){
         return "("+this.left+","+this.right+")";
        }
    }   

    public List<Interval> getUnion(List<Interval> intervals){
        Collections.sort(intervals);
        List<Interval> union = new ArrayList<Interval>();
        int left = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int right = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        for(Interval i:intervals){
            int currentRight = i.getRight();
            int currentLeft = i.getLeft();
            if(currentLeft <= right && currentRight > right){
              right = currentRight;
            }
            if(currentLeft < left && currentRight >= right){
              left = currentLeft;
              right = currentRight; 
            }
            if(currentLeft > right){
              union.add(new Interval(left,right));
              left = currentLeft;
              right = currentRight;
            }
        }
        union.add(new Interval(left,right));
        return union;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
      System.out.println("Testing out the union");
      IntervalUnion intervalUnion = new IntervalUnion();  
      IntervalUnion.Interval i1 = intervalUnion.new Interval(2,4);
      IntervalUnion.Interval i2 = intervalUnion.new Interval(1,1);
      IntervalUnion.Interval i3 = intervalUnion.new Interval(3,4);
      IntervalUnion.Interval i4 = intervalUnion.new Interval(0,3);
      IntervalUnion.Interval i5 = intervalUnion.new Interval(8,11);
      IntervalUnion.Interval i6 = intervalUnion.new Interval(7,8);
      IntervalUnion.Interval i7 = intervalUnion.new Interval(5,7);
      IntervalUnion.Interval i8 = intervalUnion.new Interval(9,11);
      IntervalUnion.Interval i9 = intervalUnion.new Interval(13,13);
      IntervalUnion.Interval i10 = intervalUnion.new Interval(16,17);
      IntervalUnion.Interval i11 = intervalUnion.new Interval(12,15);
      IntervalUnion.Interval i12 = intervalUnion.new Interval(12,14);

      List<IntervalUnion.Interval> sample = new ArrayList<IntervalUnion.Interval>()
                    {{
                      add(i1);
                      add(i2);
                      add(i3);
                      add(i4);
                      add(i5);
                      add(i6);
                      add(i7);
                      add(i8);
                      add(i9);
                      add(i10);
                      add(i11);
                      add(i12); 
                    }};

        for (IntervalUnion.Interval i:intervalUnion.getUnion(sample)){
        System.out.println(i);
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: Your solution relies on a sort so it has time complexity O(nlogn). If you are dealing with a particularly large number of intervals you should look into line sweep, which can give you O(n) complexity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No comments about the logic (yet?), but I do have something else to comment...

## Validation

You should validate that the `left` field is never greater than the `right` field during instantiation, since your comparison logic makes use of that.

## Endpoints

Slightly pernickety on this, but since your intervals includes both endpoints, your `toString()` representation should be using square braces instead of parentheses... See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_%28mathematics%29#Notations_for_intervals) for more info.

## `static` classes?

If you make `Interval` a static class, you can 'freely' create instances without bounding to an instance of `IntervalUnion`. This really depends on your use case...

## Comparisons

Your `compareTo(Interval)` code can be replaced by [`Integer.compareTo(int, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#compare-int-int-).

## Creating `List`s

Using [`Arrays.asList()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-) is probably what you want, instead of the double-brace initialization...

## Proper unit testing, please

Just displaying the output is not a unit test, you should assert that the output of calling `intervalUnion.getUnion(sample)` matches an expected `Collection` of `Interval` objects. For more info: [Unit testing = Arrange, Act and Assert (link to another good CR answer)](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/84912/27975).

## What's good

I like that your `Interval` class is immutable.

## Other suggestions

I wonder if this is a good case for Stream reduction operations...

**edit:** I now have my own take on your question/approach here, using stream reduction:

[Onion Run Festival (or the unexpected anagram for Union of Intervals)](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/85089/onion-run-festival-or-the-unexpected-anagram-for-union-of-intervals)