# Onion Run Festival (or the unexpected anagram for Union of Intervals)

Tags: java, rags-to-riches, interval

Original question: [Union of intervals](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/85044/union-of-intervals)

In the original code, the `Interval` model class implements `Comparable` so that an input of `List<Interval>` objects can and must be sorted first for the logic to apply. I have decided to stick with the same approach, but applied a stream reduction operation to get our `List<Interval>` output. I will also point out any other differences as we go along...

## `Interval` model class

```
public final class Interval implements Comparable<Interval> {

    public final int lowerInclusive;
    public final int upperInclusive;
    private final int hashCode;

    private Interval(int first, int second) {
        lowerInclusive = Math.min(first, second);
        upperInclusive = Math.max(first, second);
        hashCode = Arrays.hashCode(new int[]{ lowerInclusive, upperInclusive});
    }

    public boolean startsOneAfter(int index) {
        return lowerInclusive > index + 1;
    }

    public boolean endsAfter(int index) {
        return upperInclusive > index;
    }

    /**
     * The natural ordering between two {@link Interval} objects ({@code this} and
     * {@code other}) are as follows:
     * <ul>
     * <li>If {@code this} starts lower than {@code other}, {@code this} is lesser.</li>
     * <li>If {@code this} starts higher than {@code other}, {@code this} is greater.</li>
     * <li>If {@code this} starts the same as {@code other}:</li>
     * <ul>
     * <li>If {@code this} ends lower than {@code other}, {@code this} is lesster.</li>
     * <li>If {@code this} ends higher than {@code other}, {@code this} is greater.</li>
     * </ul>
     * <li>{@code 0} is returned only if {@code this.equals(other) == true}.</li>
     * </ul>
     *
     * @param other the other {@link Interval} to compare
     * @return a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as {@code this} is
     *         less than, equal to, or greater than the {@code other}
     */
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Interval other) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(other);
        int result = Integer.compare(lowerInclusive, other.lowerInclusive);
        return result == 0 ?
                Integer.compare(upperInclusive, other.upperInclusive) : result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        return o instanceof Interval
                && lowerInclusive == ((Interval) o).lowerInclusive
                && upperInclusive == ((Interval) o).upperInclusive;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return hashCode;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "[" + lowerInclusive + "," + upperInclusive + "]";
    }

    public static Interval of(int first, int second) {
        return new Interval(first, second);
    }
}
```

- Constructor is flexible enough to take in two `int` values in any order.
- Yes, `lowerInclusive` and `upperInclusive` are public fields, since my class is already immutable, the fields are immutable and therefore I think I should be able to do away with public getter methods this way. Correct me if I'm wrong. :)
- Implemented `equals()` and `hashCode()` for good measure.
- `startsOneAfter()` and `endsAfter()` are helper methods to facilitate the logic in `IntervalCollector` below.
- The implementation of `compareTo()` is more robust now, as it considers the upper bound as well. See its Javadoc for more details.

## `IntervalCollector` `Collector` implementation for reduction

```
/**
 * A {@link Collector} for union-ing {@link Interval} objects.
 *
 */
public class IntervalCollector implements
        Collector<Interval, IntervalCollector, List<Interval>> {

    private boolean init = false;
    private final List<Interval> result = new ArrayList<>();
    private int lowerInclusive = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    private int upperInclusive = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

    private IntervalCollector add() {
        result.add(Interval.of(lowerInclusive, upperInclusive));
        return this;
    }

    private void copy(final Interval interval) {
        lowerInclusive = interval.lowerInclusive;
        extend(interval);
    }

    private void extend(final Interval interval) {
        upperInclusive = interval.upperInclusive;
    }

    @Override
    public BiConsumer<IntervalCollector, Interval> accumulator() {
        return (collector, interval) -> {
            if (!init) {
                collector.copy(interval);
                init = true;
            } else if (interval.startsOneAfter(collector.upperInclusive)) {
                collector.add().copy(interval);
            } else if (interval.endsAfter(collector.upperInclusive)) {
                collector.extend(interval);
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Characteristics> characteristics() {
        return EnumSet.noneOf(Characteristics.class);
    }

    @Override
    public BinaryOperator<IntervalCollector> combiner() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Function<IntervalCollector, List<Interval>> finisher() {
        return collector -> {
            return Collections.unmodifiableList(collector.add().result); };
    }

    @Override
    public Supplier<IntervalCollector> supplier() {
        return IntervalCollector::new;
    }
}
```

- `add()`, `copy()` and `extend()` are helper methods to manage the internal state of a `IntervalCollector` instance.
- The main logic inside `accumulator` is quite straight-forward, I'll put it in point form anyways:

  - If this is the first `Interval` object, we set our `lowerInclusive` and `upperInclusive`.
  - Otherwise, if this `interval` starts one greater than our current upper bound, we know we can perform an `add()` first, before 'restarting' with the current `interval` for the next element.
  - Else, if `interval` ends after our current upper bound, we can `extend()` our current upper bound.
- The output of this `Collector` is an unmodifiable `List`.

## `IntervalUnion` main utility class

```
public final class IntervalUnion {

    private IntervalUnion() {
        // empty
    }

    public static List<Interval> union(Collection<Interval> intervals) {
        return intervals.stream().sorted().collect(new IntervalCollector());
    }
}
```

- Hmms... I guess there's nothing much to say here, except the input is now just a `Collection` instead of a `List`.

## `IntervalUnionTest` test class

```
public class IntervalUnionTest {

    enum TestCase {
        MIN_VALUE(toIntervals(Integer.MIN_VALUE, Integer.MIN_VALUE),
                    toIntervals(Integer.MIN_VALUE, Integer.MIN_VALUE)),
        MAX_VALUE(toIntervals(Integer.MAX_VALUE, Integer.MAX_VALUE),
                    toIntervals(Integer.MAX_VALUE, Integer.MAX_VALUE)),
        NEGATIVE_INTERVALS(toIntervals(-9, -10, -4, -4, -6, -8, -2, -1),
                            toIntervals(-10, -6, -4, -4, -2, -1)),
        AROUND_ZERO(toIntervals(-3, -2, 1, 0, 2, 3), toIntervals(-3, -2, 0, 3)),
        POSITIVE_INTERVALS(toIntervals(1, 2, 2, 5, 4, 7, 11, 9), toIntervals(1, 7, 9, 11)),
        PSEUDORANDOM(toIntervals(2, 4, 1, 1, 3, 4, 0, 3, 8, 11, 7, 8,
                                5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 13, 16, 17, 12, 15, 12, 14),
                    toIntervals(0, 17));

        /**
         * Helper method to group pairs of arguments into {@link Interval} objects.
         *
         * @param values the values to convert to {@link Interval} objects
         * @return a {@link List} of {@link Interval} objects
         * @throws IllegalArgumentException if {@code values} is null or not in pairs
         */
        private static List<Interval> toIntervals(int... values) {
            if (values == null || values.length % 2 != 0) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Values must not be null and in pairs.");
            }
            List<Interval> result = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < values.length - 1; i++) {
                result.add(Interval.of(values[i], values[++i]));
            }
            return result;
        }

        private final Collection<Interval> input;
        private final List<Interval> expected;

        private TestCase(final Collection<Interval> input, final List<Interval> expected) {
            this.input = input;
            this.expected = expected;
        }

        public List<Interval> doTest() {
            final List<Interval> result = IntervalUnion.union(input);
            assertThat(result, equalTo(expected));
            return result;
        }
    }

    @DataProvider(name = "test-cases")
    public Iterator<Object[]> getTestCases() {
        return Arrays.stream(TestCase.values()).map(v -> { return new Object[]{ v }; }).iterator();
    }

    @Test(dataProvider = "test-cases")
    public void test(final TestCase testCase) {
        testCase.doTest().forEach(System.out::println);
        System.out.println("-----");
    }
}
```

- `toIntervals()` is a helper method to make it *slightly easier* to create `Interval` objects from pairs of `int` values.
- Testing is done via TestNG and its parameterized testing approach using a `@DataProvider`.

  - Test cases are represented (encapsulated?) as `enum`s and an `Iterator` is created from mapping each `enum` value inside a `Object[]` wrapper to 'feed' our test method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Interval

Your interval class is neat, well, structured in general. The hashCode/equals/compareTo contracts all look accurate. I like the Java-8-like use of the `of(...)` factory method.

The `compareTo` method is fine, but, I wonder whether it is better to express that as a `Comparator` call. Java8 has some nice comparator extensions, you should use them... oh, that's a problem.

You don't have getters/setters for your lower/upper Intervals. You should have those (and the values should be `private`):

```
public int getLowerInclusive() {
    return lowerInclusive;
}

public int getUpperInclusive() {
    return upperInclusive;
}
```

Now, with those methods, you can have a comparator:

```
private static final Comparator<Interval> NATURAL = Comparator
        .comparingInt(Interval::getLowerInclusive)
        .thenComparingInt(Interval::getUpperInclusive);
```

And, with that comparator, you can make your `compareTo()` method:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Interval other) {
    return NATURAL.compare(this, other);
}
```

While we are still in this class, I found the following method to have a really misleading name:

```
public boolean startsOneAfter(int index) {
    return lowerInclusive > index + 1;
}
```

That should not even exist on the class. It is something that should be calculated outside the class, and even then, should be called `nonExtending` or something. I'll come back to this...

### IntervalCollector

This class is where I feel your largest problems are. They are implementation, and usability problems. It boils down to two things, with two consequences:

1. you assume sorted data
2. you have no combiner

This means that:

1. you cannot start processing the first data until all the data is sorted, you have a latency problem.
2. you cannot process data in parallel, you have a scalability problem.

Almost all the value of the streams API is in those two features, and you've denied yourself access to them.

Fixing this is a problem, more of a problem than is easy in a review, but, the bottom line is that your Collector needs to be smarter.

A good start to fixing it would be to implement the `combiner()` method, which would lead you down the path required to support a merging `accumulator` too. <strike>I have some ideas of how I would do it, but it's more than is reasonable for this answer ;-)</strike>

Here's a way I would do it:

#### Interval

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;

public final class Interval implements Comparable<Interval> {

    private static final Comparator<Interval> NATURAL = Comparator
            .comparingInt(Interval::getLowerInclusive).thenComparingInt(
                    Interval::getUpperInclusive);

    private final int lowerInclusive;
    private final int upperInclusive;
    private final int hashCode;

    private Interval(int first, int second) {
        lowerInclusive = Math.min(first, second);
        upperInclusive = Math.max(first, second);
        hashCode = Arrays
                .hashCode(new int[] { lowerInclusive, upperInclusive });
    }

    public boolean startsOneAfter(int index) {
        return lowerInclusive > index + 1;
    }

    public boolean endsAfter(int index) {
        return upperInclusive > index;
    }

    public int getLowerInclusive() {
        return lowerInclusive;
    }

    public int getUpperInclusive() {
        return upperInclusive;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Interval other) {
        return NATURAL.compare(this, other);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        return o instanceof Interval
                && lowerInclusive == ((Interval) o).lowerInclusive
                && upperInclusive == ((Interval) o).upperInclusive;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return hashCode;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "[" + lowerInclusive + "," + upperInclusive + "]";
    }

    public static Interval of(int first, int second) {
        return new Interval(first, second);
    }
}
```

#### IntervalCollector

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ListIterator;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.function.BiConsumer;
import java.util.function.BinaryOperator;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.function.Supplier;
import java.util.stream.Collector;

public class IntervalCollector implements
        Collector<Interval, IntervalCollector, List<Interval>> {

    private final List<Interval> members = new LinkedList<>();

    private void include(final Interval merge) {

        final ListIterator<Interval> it = members.listIterator();

        final int lowLimit = merge.getLowerInclusive() - 1;
        final int highLimit = merge.getUpperInclusive() + 1;

        while (it.hasNext()) {
            final Interval left = it.next();
            if (lowLimit <= left.getUpperInclusive()) {
                if (highLimit <= left.getLowerInclusive()) {
                    // non overlapping, insert before.
                    it.previous();
                    it.add(merge);
                    return;
                }
                if (left.getLowerInclusive() <= merge.getLowerInclusive()
                        && merge.getUpperInclusive() <= left
                                .getUpperInclusive()) {
                    // we are a complete subset of the item that is there.
                    return;
                }
                // overlapping....
                final int nlow = Math.min(merge.getLowerInclusive(),
                        left.getLowerInclusive());
                int max = Math.max(merge.getUpperInclusive(),
                        left.getUpperInclusive());
                it.remove();
                while (it.hasNext()) {
                    Interval t = it.next();
                    if (highLimit < t.getLowerInclusive()) {
                        // then t is beyond our span....
                        it.previous();
                        break;
                    }
                    // t is within our span.
                    it.remove();
                    max = Math.max(max, t.getUpperInclusive());
                }
                it.add(Interval.of(nlow, max));
                return;
            }
        }
        // nothing matched, we are at the end.
        it.add(merge);

    }

    private IntervalCollector merge(IntervalCollector with) {
        with.members.forEach(i -> include(i));
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public Supplier<IntervalCollector> supplier() {
        return IntervalCollector::new;
    }

    @Override
    public BiConsumer<IntervalCollector, Interval> accumulator() {
        return (collector, interval) -> collector.include(interval);
    }

    @Override
    public BinaryOperator<IntervalCollector> combiner() {
        return (a, b) -> a.merge(b);
    }

    @Override
    public Function<IntervalCollector, List<Interval>> finisher() {
        return ic -> new ArrayList<>(ic.members);
    }

    @Override
    public Set<java.util.stream.Collector.Characteristics> characteristics() {
        return Collections.singleton(Characteristics.UNORDERED);
    }

}
```

### IntervalMain

This is where I think the flawed Collector logic is most obvious... your code is:

> ```
> public static List<Interval> union(Collection<Interval> intervals) {
>     return intervals.stream().sorted().collect(new IntervalCollector());
> }
> ```

But, if the `sorted()` is removed, your code will fail.

If `parallel()` is added, your code will fail.

Requiring that the user adds stages to their stream is an invitation for problems in the future...

Comment: Updated to include an implementation of a parallel and unsorted capability

Comment: Thanks for this well-written answer, as always. :) Yeah, when I saw the original code relying on a sorted input I knew that was a bit iffy, but decided to base my approach on it anyways with that caveat in mind. Good to know of a better solution that removes that requirement. Just one question, the `Interval` class doesn't need to be `Comparable` for your `IntervalCollector` to work right?

Comment: Correct, no need for comparable in the Interval. I am not happy with the LinkedList, as it happens, I did consider a binary-search, but that has O(n) insert/remove